How to use @ConfigurationProperties with @Conditional in Spring
I like strong typing and refactoring capabilities of @ConfigurationProperites. I want conditional beans, but don't want to use @ConditionalOnProperty because it requires raw property name.
I tried this approach
@Conditional(SecurityEnabledCondition.class)
@Bean ...


public class SecurityEnabledCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    ClientProperties clientProperties = context.getBeanFactory().getBean(ClientProperties.class);
    return clientProperties.isSecured();
  }
}

But the bean is not found as the Condition is not designed to interact with beans. How to use @ConfigurationProperties with @Conditional in Spring?

You don't. You must not access beans from the context in a condition.

You have done the correct implementation. You can get beans from the context, like the OnBeanCondition class does. I think your bean is not found for some other reason.

The OnBeanCondition doesn't get beans it gets the types or names and for that it doesn' tneed beans but rather only the BeanDefinition. The simple fact that you should never interact with beans is even in the documentation.

Condition implementations shouldn't interact with beans. This is clearly stated in the javadoc of the class. (emphasis is mine).

Conditions must follow the same restrictions as a BeanFactoryPostProcessor and take care to never interact with bean instances.

This is due to the fact that they operate on the BeanFactory very early on in the process, at that moment there aren't any beans. If you now start interacting with beans it will lead to premature initialization of beans and more. Hence you shouldn't do that.
You should either use the @ConditionalOnProperty and specify the property to check or you must check the property inside your custom SecurityEnabledCondition. But don't try to get beans from the context.

Although true, it's really annoying in case you want to check more complex properties. For instance, there is no easy way to query a list of values.
